# Mount filesystem image placed in a static variable

Tags: c++, linux, filesystems

It's possible to loop mount a binary file that contains a filesystem image. I'd like to put that binary file into a C static variable, and then mount that. Is this possible? If so, what C API magic do I need?

Comment: Certainly this is possible. To clarify, you want to do it all from within the binary itself, and avoid shelling out to external `losetup` and `mount` commands?

Comment: Shelling out is fine (possible to do this in a script?), but I'm interested in the C API calls.

Comment: "but I'm interested in the C API calls" -- sorry, I don't understand. If you know how to do this via external commands, then you can find out which APIs these commands use. So do you _already_ know how to do this and are having trouble discovering the APIs, or are you stuck on an earlier "how do I do this at all?" stage?

Comment: Not quite. I know how to mount files. Sure I can write my static variable out to a file, and do it that way. I was hoping that there was some magic that would allow me to mount a buffer in memory directly.

Answer (score 1):

There are several steps we'll want to take

1. Create a file system image
2. Embed this image into the binary
3. Mount the embedded image as a read-only file system.

It sounds like you already know how to perform stems 1 and 2, but not how to do step 3.

I prepared `ab.sqfs` image and `a.out` which contains that image at offset `0x3010`. Here are the commands to mount this filesystem:

```
# optional, look at the bytes of the filesystem from step 1 
xxd -l 16 -g1 ab.sqfs
00000000: 68 73 71 73 07 00 00 00 6c 61 ce 60 00 00 02 00  hsqs....la.`....

# optional: confirm that we have the correct file offset to the start of FS image
xxd -l 16 -g1 -s 0x3010 a.out
00003010: 68 73 71 73 07 00 00 00 6c 61 ce 60 00 00 02 00  hsqs....la.`....

# create a loop device which "points" into the file:
sudo losetup -r -o 0x3010 loop0 a.out 
losetup: a.out: Warning: file does not fit into a 512-byte sector; the end of the file will be ignored.

# optional: confirm that (just created) /dev/loop0 contains expected bytes
sudo xxd -l 16 -g1 /dev/loop0
00000000: 68 73 71 73 07 00 00 00 6c 61 ce 60 00 00 02 00  hsqs....la.`....

# create directory on which the FS will be mounted
mkdir /tmp/mnt         

# finally mount the FS:
sudo mount -oro /dev/loop0 /tmp/mnt

# optional: verify contents of /tmp/mnt
ls -lR /tmp/mnt
... has exactly the files I've put into it.
```

> what C API magic do I need?

You can run the `losetup` and `mount` commands under `strace` to observe what they do. The key steps for `losetup` are:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/a.out", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/loop0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
ioctl(4, LOOP_SET_FD, 3)                = 0
ioctl(4, LOOP_SET_STATUS64, {lo_offset=0x3010, lo_number=0, lo_flags=LO_FLAGS_READ_ONLY, lo_file_name="/tmp/a.out", ...}) = 0
```

And for `mount`:

```
mount("/dev/loop0", "/tmp/mnt", "squashfs", MS_RDONLY, NULL) = 0
```

These calls can be performed by the application itself, or by "shelling out" to external `losetup` and `mount` commands.

Comment: Thank you for this. Sadly you simply write the static buffer out to a standard file, and then loop mount that file. Pretty standard stuff. Is there no way to share the buffer in some way, so that the in-memory data appears as a file that then may be loop mounted directly?

Comment: @bobbogo No, I _don't_.